# App not processing events while trying to open database connection

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, azure-sql-database

I am writing a Windows Forms app in C# with Visual Studio 2022 on a Windows 10 machine.  The app connects to an Azure database, which works fine.  My issue is that sometimes it takes several seconds to connect (maybe 10 or so), or if there is an error it goes all the way to the timeout limit (usually 20 to 30 seconds) before coming back with whatever error message there is.

I am trying to provide some visual feedback to the user during this time, but the application does not appear to be processing any events, so whatever type of feedback I'm trying to send does not get done until the operation completes (at which point it is moot).

Any ideas on how to deal with this?  Do I need to open the database on a different thread, and if so, will that be an issue throughout the rest of the app whenever I use the database object opened on a different thread?

I'm trying something simple, like gradually adding a row of dots, like so:

```
        private void InitCloudDatabase()
        {
            Boolean success = true;


            WorkingTimer.Enabled = true;
            WorkingTimer.Start();

            try
            {
                AzureAgDatabase db = new AzureAgDatabase();
                db.OpenConnection();
            }
            catch
            {
                success = false;
            }

            WorkingTimer.Stop();

            pbCloudResult.Image = (success) ? Properties.Resources.icons8_done_96 :
                                              Properties.Resources.Red_X___Fail;
        }

        private void WorkingTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblCloud.Text += " .";
            if (lblCloud.Text.Contains(" . . . . . . . . . . .")) 
            { 
                lblCloud.Text = "Database Connection (Cloud)"; 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really worked with Windows Forms before, but in most UI based applications, you should reserve the UI Thread for just UI operations and move all time consuming tasks (Compute or I/O) to a different thread to ensure that the UI is still responsive.

In the case of Windows Forms, looks like you have a [`BackgroundWorker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=net-7.0) class that you can use to offload the DB operations into. Here is [a walkthrough in the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/walkthrough-implementing-a-form-that-uses-a-background-operation?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) that you can refer to.

Another approach would be to use the [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-7.0) class to run your database code asynchronously, with lesser code compared to the first approach. You would simply wrap statements that take time in a [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-7.0) call and have follow up statements in a [continuation task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/chaining-tasks-by-using-continuation-tasks#continuations-and-child-tasks).